# While executing my stored procedure, I'm getting this error while my input is multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SP.
I'm getting this error - "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

```
enter code here

ALTER PROCEDURE GetToDoDetails
@ClientID VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ClientID = REPLACE(@ClientID,',',''',''')
SET @Sql=
'SELECT
 C.ClientID,
C.ClientToDoID,
C.AssignedToID,
C.ToBeCompletedBy,
C.ToDoTypeID,
S.UDDescription,
(CL.LastName +'',''+ CL.FirstName) "Client Name",
(Select count(ClientID) from c_ToDo WHERE ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID+''') GROUP BY ClientID) "CountRow"
FROM c_ToDo C
INNER JOIN s_UserDefinedOptions S ON C.ToDoTypeID = S.UDID
INNER JOIN c_Client CL ON C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
WHERE 
C.ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID + ''')
ORDER BY C.ClientID ASC'
EXEC (@Sql)
GO
```

If I write

```
EXEC GetToDoDetails '1566'
```

, I'm getting this result(refer image)

[image]

Now if I write

```
EXEC GetToDoDetails '1566,1697'
```

It is showing the error which I told about.
After Adding TOP 1 in my subquery as

```
(Select TOP 1 count(ClientID) from c_ToDo WHERE ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID + ''')
```

I'm getting the count for first record only for different clientIDs(1566 & 1697).(refer image)
[image]

After the 45th record for ClientID=1566(total row count is 45 for 1566),
I want the count to change for ClientID=1697(which is 63).
I don't know how to approach this. I'm a newbie. Please help.

Comment: GAH!!! SQL Injection isn't your friend.

Comment: Please include sample input and output data as *text* (use `<pre>` element to avoid formatting): those images are too small to read. Also please describe what you want (not just how the data should appear in one example)

Comment: Are you trying to pass multiple values in Array list of strings ? You should split strings if that is case `SET @ClientID = REPLACE(@ClientID,',',''',''')` does only return one ClientID with concat values

Comment: Suggest replacing a string split with a table valued parameter. Then you can join to it in the query and avoid the dynamic SQL.

Comment: why don't you print the query, instead of executing it, and check yourself where are you getting that duplicate data?

Comment: I want the count of rows generated by the value of ClientID or multiple ClientIDs which I'm passing while Executing my SP(GetToDoDetails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not ideal to have a subquery in select statement for count, In your query you are getting multiple values as `client id` has multiple values, I would prefer to bring it down in join statement. `Print @sql` should work to check if statement is valid. This will do the trick for you

```
    DECLARE @ClientID VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ClientID = REPLACE('1566,1697,2467',',',''',''') 
    SET @Sql=
    'SELECT
     C.ClientID,
    C.ClientToDoID,
    C.AssignedToID,
    C.ToBeCompletedBy,
    C.ToDoTypeID,
    S.UDDescription,
    (CL.LastName +'',''+ CL.FirstName) "Client Name",
     "CountRow"
    FROM c_ToDo C
    INNER JOIN s_UserDefinedOptions S ON C.ToDoTypeID = S.UDID
    INNER JOIN c_Client CL ON C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
    INNER JOIN (Select count(*) CountRow,ClientID from c_ToDo WHERE ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID+''') GROUP BY ClientID) CO
    on C.ClientID = CO.ClientID
    WHERE 
    C.ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID + ''')
    ORDER BY C.ClientID ASC'
    PRINT (@Sql)
```

Your SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetToDoDetails
    @ClientID VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    AS
   BEGIN 
          DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @ClientID = REPLACE(@ClientID,',',''',''') 
            SET @Sql=
            'SELECT
             C.ClientID,
            C.ClientToDoID,
            C.AssignedToID,
            C.ToBeCompletedBy,
            C.ToDoTypeID,
            S.UDDescription,
            (CL.LastName +'',''+ CL.FirstName) "Client Name",
             "CountRow"
            FROM c_ToDo C
            INNER JOIN s_UserDefinedOptions S ON C.ToDoTypeID = S.UDID
            INNER JOIN c_Client CL ON C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
            INNER JOIN (Select count(*) CountRow,ClientID from c_ToDo WHERE ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID+''') GROUP BY ClientID) CO
            on C.ClientID = CO.ClientID
            WHERE 
            C.ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID + ''')
            ORDER BY C.ClientID ASC'
            PRINT (@Sql)
            EXEC  (@Sql)
END
```

Comment: This still suffers SQL Injection.

Comment: Alias table names and include in square braces is  a simple trick to stop it

Comment: @ven is it true to stop sql injection, i have read it elsewhere, enclosing table alias names in () will prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @Ven how will quoting the parameter stop injection? `ClientID` isn't a dynamic object, it's a delimited list. quoting it would turn an input list of `'1,2,3,4'` into one of following values (after the `REPLACE`): `['1','2','3','4']` or `['1'],['2'],['3'],['4']`. That isn't going to work...

Comment: @Larnu It would be ideal to find an article about this. I am saying about Aliasing table names in () , not parameters, it wont return anything if table is protected from injection

Comment: Do you mean an article about SQL injection? a Parenthesis, in T-SQL, however, isn't a quote operator either. Try `SELECT name FROM (sys).(syslogins);`. You'll get an error.

Comment: Lol ofcos, it will throw an error.  Alias a table as pro and enclose it as (pro)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am sure it will, do not worry about SQL injection. every organisation has its own needs. But its worth of considering security aspect of every code.

Comment: "do not worry about SQL injection"?! Attitudes like that are why it **is** a problem.

Comment: @Larnu lets not get into heated discussions. I guess u haven't read whole message.It is always ideal not to use dynamic SQL as u explained, my experience with most developers and DBA's tend to prefer a simple way of solving issue. hope you do understand. All the Best

Comment: I disagree, as well, that its "always ideal to not use dynamic SQL", neither did I state so. There are certainly plenty of times where there is a need for it, and I make a lot of use of it. I'm simply stating that if you do use it, paremetrise it correctly and avoid injection; which isn't the case on your answer. It seems, however, that you disagree with that, and would prefer to leave things open to injection. That is your choice, but, it is far from the right idea. Thanks for discussion anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There's some guess work in there, however, SQL Injection is not your friend. That needs to go, NOW. I've therefore used a Table Type Parameter instead.

In regards to the error, that was due to the statement:

```
(Select count(ClientID) from c_ToDo WHERE ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID+''') GROUP BY ClientID) "CountRow"
```

This'll return multiple rows if you had more than one value in `@ClientID`. Also, the quote operator in SQL Server for an object is a bracket (`[]`), not double quotes (`"`).

Anyway, this is a guess, but this should get you on the right path (I hope):

```
CREATE TYPE ClientList AS TABLE (ClientID int); --Datatype is GUESSED
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetToDoDetails @Client ClientList READONLY
AS
    SELECT C.ClientID,
           C.ClientToDoID,
           C.AssignedToID,
           C.ToBeCompletedBy,
           C.ToDoTypeID,
           S.UDDescription,
           (CL.LastName + ',' + CL.FirstName) AS [Client Name],
           COUNT(C.ClientID) OVER (PARTITION BY C.ClientID) AS [CountRow] --Total guess here
                                                                          --If this is meant to just be a count of EVERY row, remove the PARTITION BY clause (so just OVER())
    FROM c_ToDo C
         INNER JOIN s_UserDefinedOptions S ON C.ToDoTypeID = S.UDID
         INNER JOIN c_Client CL ON C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Client e WHERE C.ClientID = e.ClientID) --Changed from IN to EXISTS
    ORDER BY C.ClientID ASC;
GO
```

Comment: I'd love to hear the reason for the Downvote here. Many thanks,

Comment: Not me, i have just upvoted.