# Getting conversion error while trying to remove the @sql variable and Replace from my code

Tags: sql-server

Can someone remove the `@sql` variable and `Replace` function for `@ClientID` & directly write the `Select` query inside the stored procedure?

I'm getting some conversion error.

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetToDoDetails
    @ClientID VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ClientID = REPLACE(@ClientID, ',', ''',''') 
    SET @Sql = 'SELECT
             C.ClientID,
            C.ClientToDoID,
            C.AssignedToID,
            C.ToBeCompletedBy,
            C.ToDoTypeID,
            S.UDDescription,
            (CL.LastName +'',''+ CL.FirstName) "Client Name",
             "CountRow"
            FROM c_ToDo C
            INNER JOIN s_UserDefinedOptions S ON C.ToDoTypeID = S.UDID
            INNER JOIN c_Client CL ON C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
            INNER JOIN (Select count(*) CountRow,ClientID from c_ToDo WHERE ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID+''') GROUP BY ClientID) CO
            on C.ClientID = CO.ClientID
            WHERE 
            C.ClientID IN (''' + @ClientID + ''')
            ORDER BY C.ClientID ASC'

    PRINT (@Sql)
    EXEC (@Sql)
END
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see you're still a fan of SQL Injection... Have a look at the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437782/3484879) I gave and you wouldn't be in this position.

Comment: Ok, brother and going to search now what actually is SQL injection.

Comment: [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection). *By the way, I don't believe we are related? Unless you know someone that I don't? O.o*